# problem uploading audio and video files on server using c#?

Tags: c#

this is the code i have used:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {                
                HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                string fileExt=System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName);
                int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;
                if (nFileLen == 0)
                {
                    lblOutput.Text = "No file was uploaded.";
                    return;
                }

                ClientFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);


                if (fileExt.Equals(".jpg") || fileExt.Equals(".gif"))
                {
                    ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathI, ClientFileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ServerFileName));
                    lblOutput.Text = "Image uploaded successfully";
                }
                else if(fileExt.Equals(".mp3"))
                {
                     ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathA, ClientFileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ServerFileName));
                    lblOutput.Text = "Audio uploaded successfully";
                }
                else if (fileExt.Equals(".mp4"))
                {
                    ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathV, ClientFileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ServerFileName));
                    lblOutput.Text = "Video uploaded successfully";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "No File is selected to upload";
        }
```

When I took the project type as website it works fine.
But I want the web application but in that only images are being upload not audio and video.

Comment: So what exactly is failing? What is `fileExt` in the failing case? (And why are you explicitly calling Equals instead of using the more readable == form?)

Comment: yes i was getting error of maximum request length..as soon as I increase that value it done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to upload a file larger than 4MB which is the default maximum allowed size. You may try increasing it in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
<!-- Set the maximum upload file size to 100MB -->
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="102400" />
```